# How to setup reverse dns for Virtual dedicated server(godaddy)

Tags: reverse-dns, domain-name-system

I have a problem in resolving the domain and found out that there is a issue with dns settings.

I wanted to configure Reverse DNS for my virtual dedicated server(windows).  My isp is godaddy.

How do i know whether my server dns settings are correctly configured?

I have Plesk with windows server.

Please kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your should forward all your requests about reverse zone to your ISP support (GoDaddy). They are responsible for reverse DNS zone.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Reverse DNS (also called PTR or pointer) first then use this tool you can check if it's correctly set: [DNSWatch](http://www.dnswatch.info)

Type in the IP address you want to check the Reverse DNS for in  the box under `DNS Lookup / IP lookup`.

At the top of the page it tells you which Servers looked up the Reverse DNS for you.

At the bottom look at this part:

`Domain Type    TTL Answer`

`Answer` is the current Reverse DNS entry. Bear in mind it can take a day to update if you change it.